# BixBy: doesn't declare itself as `library` and will not be imported in the future

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

In my capsule.bxb, I have imported
`viv.core`
`viv.navigation`
`viv.common`
`viv.time`
`viv.geo`

However, I get above warning to all the library except for core. and if I remove all these, I get the error. So what is this and how to remove the warning?

Comment: While I enjoy the stylized "BixBy" name, the official name of the assistant is simply "Bixby" :).

Answer (score 1):

If you are seeing `ERROR_DEPRECATED` warnings, you can ignore them for now. Those are coming from Bixby libraries and will be addressed soon. But Your capsule should still be able to compile and work the way it is supposed to.